# Django admin change list view disable sorting for some fields

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-1.7

Is there are way(s) to disable the sorting function for some fields in django admin change list so for those fields, users cannot click the column header to sort the list.

I tried on the following method, but it doesn't work.

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2580/

I also tired to override the changelist_view in ModelAdmin but also nothing happen.

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    self.ordering_fields = ['id']
    return super(MyModelAdmin, self).changelist_view(request, extra_context)
```

In the above case, I would like to only allow user to sort the list by ID.

Anyone has suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Django 1.7 (or the version that I last use) do not support such things. One possible dirty work-around could be defining a model class method and using that method instead of model field.

```
class TestClass(Model):
    some_field = (.....)
    other_field = (........)

    def show_other_field(self):
        return self.other_field

class TestClassAdmin(ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ("some_field", "show_other_field")
```

Since `show_other_field` is a model class method, django do not knows how to sort (or process) the return result of that method.

But as I said, this is a dirty hack that might require more processing (and maybe more database calls) according to use-case than displaying a field of a model.

Extra: If you want to make a model method **sortable**, you must pass `admin_order_field` value like:

```
def show_other_field(self):
    return self.other_field
show_other_field.admin_order_field = "other_field"
```

That will make your model method **sortable** in admin `list_display`. But you have to pass a field or relation that is usable in the `order_by` method of database api.

```
TestClass.objects.filter(....).order_by(<admin_order_field>)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I only have this way to do it.